# Как сделать, чтобы статьи выводились снизу вверх?

Tags: php

У меня на сайте выводятся статьи сверху вниз (чем больше ид, тем НИЖЕ). Как сделать, чтобы статьи выводились снизу вверх (чем больше ид, тем ВЫШЕ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите запрос, которым получаются статьи, и измените/добавьте там `ORDER BY id DESC`.
DESC - по убывающей. У вас этого куска либо нет, либо там `ORDER BY id ASC`.